# Libraries which exist in a binary's elf DT_RUNPATH are not being chosen?

Tags: linux, gcc

I have custom built `gcc-4.7.2` in my environment. The system gcc is `gcc-4.3.4`.

I have patched the **DT_RUNPATH** for all my custom gcc's binaries and shared libraries using `patchelf --set-rpath`

However, when I run `ldd` on my 4.7.2 `cc1` it picks up the system `libstdc++` instead of the one pointed to by the **DT_RUNPATH**:

```
$ ldd /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2/cc1
        libcloog-isl.so.1 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libcloog-isl.so.1 (0x00007f072dce8000)
        ...
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f072bfe0000)
   -->  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f072bcd5000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f072babe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f072df0d000)
```

As can be seen the **DT_RUNPATH** specifies the `gcc-4.7.2` library locations:

```
$ readelf -a /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2/cc1 | grep PATH
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: \
    [/sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64: \
     /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib: \
     /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/lib64: \
     /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2]
```

I know that `libstdc++.so.6` exists in the first entry in the **DT_RUNPATH**:

```
$ ls -l /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so*
lrwxrwxrwx .../sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.17
lrwxrwxrwx .../sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.17
-rwxr-x--- .../sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
-rwxr-x--- .../sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17-gdb.py
```

I don't have an **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** set in my environment:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$
```

If I **do** set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** then it finds the correct library:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64: \
    /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib: \
    /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/lib64: \
    /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2

$ ldd /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2/cc1
        libcloog-isl.so.1 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libcloog-isl.so.1 (0x00007f072dce8000)
        ...
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f072bfe0000)
   -->  libstdc++.so.6 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdf4e560000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdf4e34b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f072df0d000)
```

- How come it doesn't pick up the library found in **DT_RUNPATH**?
- How can I force it to use the `gcc-4.7.2` libraries *without* having to use **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one of the prerequisites (`libppl.so`) also imports `libstdc++`. That prerequisite was built using the system gcc, and therefore finds `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`

```
$ ldd /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libppl.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd10db000)
        libgmpxx.so.4 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libgmpxx.so.4 (0x00007f4716f92000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f4716d26000)
    --> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4716a25000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f47167a0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4716441000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f471622c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f47174b4000)
```

Once a library has been located by the dynamic linker once, it will no longer be searched for; that location will be used for any subsequent requirements.

I resolved this by **rebuilding the prerequisites with the new gcc**.

```
$ ldd /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libppl.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd10db000)
        libgmpxx.so.4 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libgmpxx.so.4 (0x00007f4716f92000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f4716d26000)
    --> libstdc++.so.6 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4716a25000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f47167a0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4716441000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /sdk/x86_64/2.11.1/gcc-4.7.2/lib/../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f471622c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f47174b4000)
```

I'm thinking the final step is to now rebuild gcc with the newly build prerequisites.

- build prerequisites with system gcc
- build new gcc
- rebuild prerequisites with new gcc
- rebuild gcc with rebuilt prerequisites

Whether the final step is necessary I'm not sure.